# Microsoft Graph API UnableToDeserializePostBody error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, bad-request, microsoft-graph-mail

I want to create a `message` using MIME format in Microsoft Graph API, using the example from page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-send-mime-message#specify-request-header-and-mime-message-body, and I end up getting a `BadRequest (400)` result with the message `{"error":{"code":"UnableToDeserializePostBody","message":"were unable to deserialize "}}` and I can’t figure out why.

What I know so far is that the message is correctly base 64 formatted (I use the base 64 string from the example) and `content-type` is set to `text/plain`, which is all the documentation asks for.
Is there any way to have more details about the failure?
Did anyone have a similar issue?
I’m out of ideas

Thanks.

**EDIT**: this fails when specifying a `mailFolder` only.

- A request such as `POST /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/messages` works
- But `POST /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/mailFolders/{id}/messages` fails

Comment: Are you setting all the other headers the documentation asks for, like `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`? Importantly, are you calling the Outlook mail API like in the example? You only say you're using Graph.

Comment: @Noah the `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`, is when attachments are added to the message; this must go in the message, not in the HTTP request headers. And yes, this is the correct API, all other calls succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it seems that MIME support is provided by graph API as a compatibility feature, and works much more when read than written, so the best solution is to use the full `message` object in `json`, this way it can be manipulated as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I experience the same issue. The only way how I was able to workaround it, is to create mailbox as draft by POST Mime message to `/me/messages`, pickup message `id` from reply and then [move message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-move?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to proper folder by POST to `/me/messages/{draftId}/move` with json content: `{'destinationId': folderId}`